# Cordova run android cant fin JAVA_HOME even though it's correctly set

Tags: java, android, cordova, java-home

when I run `cordova run android` in my project I have this output

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/ronaizacard/Android/Sdk/
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Error: /home/ronaizacard/work/apk/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code
```

However, when I check the JAVA_HOME variable I get:

```
# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

My JAVA_HOME is defined in .zshrc and I have double checked that it is set as the source.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Running java -version also confirms that JAVA_HOME is set correctly and is on the PATH.

```
➜  ~ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

So my question is how/why does Gradle find /usr/lib/jvm/default-java, and more importantly how do I point it to the correct directory?

I have also tried find the Gradle files and change the `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` on bin but cordova dont have this

I'm running 64bit Ubuntu LTS 16

Answer (score 1):

I change `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` and worked fine